# Azure Cloud Services - Visual Studio - Add Premium SSD Storage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-rm-template

Simple question, is it possible (and how if so) to configure the Role settings in Visual Studio to deploy a D11_v2 service with premium storage attached? The IOPS on the standard D11_v2 instance is a big limiting factor for us and couldn't find a simple way to do it via Visual Studio (we deploy directly through VS so wouldn't want any manual changes to get overwritten each time.)

Comment: You cannot attach premium storage to a D-series VM; you'd need to use DS-series (same performance, same price, but with Premium Storage support).

Comment: Cool, don't currently have those as an option so will get in touch with our account manager to enable DS access, Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this with an ARM template from visual studio: [vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy)

Then you can make an template that deploys you storage, vm and connect the disks.

Comment: FYI ARM won't allow for premium storage to be attached to D-series, as D- doesn't support premium storage; requires DS-series.